# can't reach maximum performance of lettuce( spirng data redis reactive, webflux)

Tags: performance, redis, reactive, lettuce, webflux

I wrote a sample WebFlux application, which read just some data from redis and do small cpu job(md5 calculation), repeats several time.

It use spring data redis reactive

```
'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis-reactive'
```

Codes that connects redis is like this.

```
 reactiveStringRedisTemplate.opsForValue().get(keyname)
```

redis server runs at localhost

```
redis-server &
```

Full codes , you can find here

https://github.com/mouse500/redperf

It's a simple codes

And for test, I call API (/wredis) with Jmeter to loadtest

---

Problem that I think is...

this application doesn't reach maximum TPS,

It reaches CPU around 40% on my local PC.

Even though it has more room of CPU, it doesn't work any harder

Why doesn't it use resource fully?

---

In case of some other method to connect redis,

(I put connection proxy ,written in nodejs)

It showed much much higher CPU and got  much more TPS.

So I don't think it is not about Redis server performance.

Problem seems issue at "calling Redis from WebFlux application with lettuce"

---

How can I make this sample application show a maximum TPS ( CPU reach 100%) ?

What option can I try?